# Formulate a large scale linear programing model by reducing the number of similar constraints and keeping them all satisfied

Tags: mathematical-optimization, linear-programming

I would like to build a large scale LP model and solve it by an LP solver.

the model formulation :

```
 Max: sum of (constantValueP_i  * decVarX_i) from i=1 to  N
 s.t. 

     decVarT + sum of (decVarK_i ) from i=1 to I = N  <=  [sum of (constantValueP_i  * decVarX_i)  from i=1 to  N ] * constantQ

     [sum of (constantValueE_i  * decVarX_i)  from i=1 to  N ] <= [sum of (constantValueE_i )  from i=1 to  N ] * constantD

     decVarK_1 >= sum of (constantValue_1_i  * decVarX_i) from i=1 to  N - decVarT

     decVarK_2 >= sum of (constantValue_2_i  * decVarX_i) from i=1 to  N - decVarT
     …

    decVarK_L >= sum of (constantValue_L_i  * decVarX_i) from i=1 to  N - decVarT

  Decision variables: 
        decVarT , 0 <= decVarX_i <= 1, decVarK_i >= 0
```

The problem is that the number of constraints of   decVarK_j for j=1 to L and L can be very large, e.g. 100,0000.

It means that it will have 100,000 constraints in the LP, which I want to avoid.

How to combine them so that I can reduce the size of the LP model meanwhile keeping all constraints satisfied ?

I am using the solver CLP (coin-or.org/Clp) on win 7 PC with 8GB mem.

Comment: This *pseudocode* is not fun to read. You shoould improve it. It's also funny that you start with ```constraint like``` and then post your full problem. The other question is: why would you want to do this optimization (solver won't care much; preprocessing to minimize constraints could be slower than just adding them)?

Comment: Too many constraints will make the model size too large and cannot be handled by the solver due to the memory consumption.

Comment: Did you try it? It all depends on sparseness of these constraints. If you want help minimizing these constraints you should reformat your question. A more math-like description of your constraints would help.

Comment: I tried to solve a LP with 5K decision variables and 30k constraints, it ran out of memory.

Comment: how to reformulate it is  my question. And, it is also what I want to get answers even though I have tried to reduce the constraints,.

Comment: If L=100k and N=5k, the matrix ConstantValue(j,i) will have 500 million entries, and you will have an LP with at least 500 million nonzeros.  Doable on a somewhat large machine. I tried a somewhat smaller version with 100 million nonzeros and Cplex needed about 8GB (1 thread). So my estimate is you need a machine with at least 40 GB RAM.

Comment: Modern commercial solvers should cope with much larger problems. I have solved with a lot more that 100k vars and constraints in the past. A lot will depend on how dense your constraints are - if most constraints only refer to a small number of vars then you will probably need less memory. What solver did you try so far, and what size of machine did you use?

Comment: I am using the solver CLP (http://www.coin-or.org/Clp/) on win 7 PC with 8GB mem.